# boot-clj: how to build/launch unit test for class generated with gen-class

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, boot-clj, gen-class, clojure.test

In my clojure project I built several java classes using **gen-class** command. They are `[extractor.yaml YAMLExtractor YAMLExtractorFactory]`. I wanted now build unit test against those classes but I have error: **`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: extractor.yaml.YAMLExtractor`** when I run test.

File which cause the error is:
**yaml_extrator_factory.clj**

```
(ns extractor.yaml-extractor-factory
  (:gen-class :name extractor.yaml.YAMLExtractorFactory
              :extends org.apache.any23.extractor.SimpleExtractorFactory
              :implements [org.apache.any23.extractor.ExtractorFactory]
              :init init
              :constructors {[] [String org.apache.any23.rdf.Prefixes java.util.Collection String]}
              :main false)
  (:require [extractor.yaml-extractor])
  (:import [extractor.yaml YAMLExtractor]
           [org.apache.any23.rdf Prefixes]
           [org.apache.any23.extractor SimpleExtractorFactory ExtractorFactory Extractor ExtractionContext ]))
```

The error occurs only during testing. Whole project is AOT-compilable with no error and it is fine when I build a jar file as well.

The test **simple.clj** contains head:

```
(ns extractor.simple
    (:use [clojure.tools.logging :as log]
          [clojure.java.io :as jio]
          [clojure.test :as test])
    (:require [extractor.yaml-extractor-factory])
    (:import [java.util Arrays]
             [extractor.yaml.YAMLExtractorFactory]))
```

And test which prints CLASSPATH. `yaml-extractor-factory` was not used.
Test is run with command:

`boot aot -a update-classpath run-test -t extractor.simple`

where task **update-classpath** adds `(get-env :directories)` into classpath
and **run-test** runs a test. `run-test` works fine with normal clojure code.

**run-test** is my task with following content:

```
(deftask run-test "Run unit tests"
  [t test-name NAME str "Test to execute. Run all tests if not given."]

  (require '[extractor.simple])
  (with-pass-thru [_]
    (if (nil? test-name)
      (do
        (util/info "Run all tests")
        (test/run-all-tests))
      (do
        (util/info (format "Run test: %s" (:test-name *opts*)))
        (test/run-tests (symbol (:test-name *opts*)))
        ))))
```

Comment: Where does `run-test` come from? Is it your task? If yes, how is it defined?

Comment: OK. Thanks. I have added into the post. Line `(require '[extractor.simple])` is namespace with test. Otherwise there is error that namespace not found. Boot unfortunately is not able to find namespace itself.